# How to control a menu programmatically in SwiftUI on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, appkit

I'm writing a ComboBox in SwiftUI on macOS and want to control it programmatically in a flexible way, rather than click on the button and the list shows.

I can use `Menu` to create a naive menu referring to [Apple Developer - Menu](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu), but cannot find any approach to programmatically control it, like showing or hiding its list.

Then I tried to custom one with a `List` like shown below. But when that list shows, it takes place and pushes other views down, which doesn't behave like a default system `Menu` that floating in front of following views.

```swift
VStack {
    TextField("Ttitle", text: $string) { isEditing in
        onEditing = isEditing
    }
    if onEditing { List(listItems, id:\.self) { Text($0) } }
}
```

It couldn't be better if there's a method like this, but it not exists.

```swift
SomeViewHere()
    .menu(isPresented: $showMenu) {
        Button("A") {}
        Button("B") {}
        Button("C") {}
    }
```

Also, I found a post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69822148/how-to-show-menu-programmatically-in-swiftui), but it only works on iOS.

I'm not familiar with AppKit, so I don't know if a solution exists there. But I'm also glad if AppKit works and willing to learn it. Anyway, I always prefer to use native SwiftUI. So, any ideas of how to achieve that?

Comment: [`NSCombobox` in an `NSViewRepresentable`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67956554/how-to-get-a-combobox-with-swiftui) is not an option?

Comment: @vadian I tried those codes. But I don't think it's a good solution for me. First, it doesn't behave as I expected, it shows the list only when explicitly clicking on pull-down button. I wish it to show list when I'm editing (the "I" icon blinks). Second, it's not that "general" to be reused in other custom views with other behaviours. For example, to show that menu list when hovering on a view.

Comment: You can’t control SwiftUI s menu you have to create your own

Comment: @loremipsum I think so. But it doesn't behave correctly just using `VStack` as I mentioned in the post. Any idea of how to add this floating list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referred to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72314668/how-to-bring-overlay-view-to-front-in-swiftui) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64456602/how-to-apply-an-overlay-that-is-larger-than-the-underlying-view-in-swiftui), I figured out how to bring the floating list into life. An example custom one are shown below.

```swift
@State var showList: Bool = false

var body: some View {

    Button("Click Me") { showList.toggle() }
    .frame(width: 100, height: 20)
    .overlay {
        if showList {
            List {
                Button("AA") {}
                Button("AA") {}
                Button("AA") {}
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 300)
            .offset(y: 160)
        }
    }
    .zIndex(1)
    
    Text("Hello World")
    Circle().fill(.brown).frame(width: 50, height: 50)
}
```